# Django error: No Such Table, even after making migrations

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

I am getting Operational Error accessing http://127.0.0.1:8000/orders/create/

The error I get:

```
OperationalError at /orders/create/
no such table: orders_order
```

I have already tried making migrations. But the issue won't go away

My models.py look like this:

```
from django.db import models
from ecom.models import Product

# Create your models here.

class Order(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    postal_code = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    paid = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('-created',)

    def __str__(self):
        return 'Order {}'.format(self.id)

    def get_total_cost(self):
        return sum(item.get_cost() for item in self.items.all())

#item info 
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, related_name='items',on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product,related_name='order_items',on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.id)

    def get_cost(self):
        return self.price * self.quantity
```

and my views.py looks like this:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import OrderItem
from .forms import OrderCreateForm
from cart.cart import Cart

# Create your views here.
def order_create(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = OrderCreateForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            order = form.save()
            for item in cart:
                OrderItem.objects.create(order=order, product=item['product'], price=item['price'], quantity=item['quantity'])
            # clear the cart            
            cart.clear()
            return render(request, 'order/created.html', {'order': order})
    else:
        form = OrderCreateForm()
        return render(request, 'order/create.html', {'cart': cart, 'form': form})
```

The line which Django Highlights:

```
order = form.save()
```

Comment: My Django version is 2.2  please help :-)

Comment: No need to [shout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_caps#Association_with_shouting)

Comment: Has the table been created?  Check the DB.  When you run makemigrations the first time for an app you must include the app name, eg `python manage.py makemigrations app_name`.  And the app must be included in `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`

Comment: Yes I have tried both. I have made the migrations with appname and the app is already included in settings.py but still I am getting the error.

Comment: And after `makemigrations` you will need to call the `python manage.py migrate` to actually run them against your db of course :)

Comment: @azundo. Thanks it worked. I did not run ```python manage.py migrate```. It is working now :-)

Comment: @azundo Make that an answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

I fix it by running `python manage.py migrate`  after `python manage.py makemigrations orders`. Also make sure your app is included in `settings.py` file.